# Constantinopolis Taberna Building

Tags: constantinopolis

I have just completed playing Constantinopolis<sup>([BGG](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/31483/constantinopolis))</sup> for the first time and there is a rule that I think requires clarification. The Taberna utility building (Reseller) is used for purchasing goods of a type you already produce. The section of the rules quotes this as:

> The owner of this building can buy goods from the market that he can
>   produce.

I read this as I can buy as many goods as I like in accordance with the limitations of the market.

However, the graphic on the building tile (Taberna below) shows a goods cube with a number 1 next to it.

[image]

I would associate this symbol meaning either that it can only be used for a single cube, a single cube of each type, or a single type. I can't find any specific clarifications though. Does anyone know the correct rule?

[image: Constantinopolis box]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this BGG post](http://boardgamegeek.com/article/5651920#5651920) you were correct in your initial interpretation and the "one" is a misprint:

> unfortunately it was a misprint on the Taberna tile. [...] The correct symbol is the one printed on the board, [...] you are not restricted, you can use [the Taberna] as many times as you wish.

So yes, the rules are correct. You can buy any goods that you would not otherwise be able to buy (because you can produce them), but within the limitations of the current market.